# Brackets, remembering previous session

Tags: adobe-brackets

Every time I open brackets, it points to a start-up folder instead of previously opened files and folder. Is there a way to retain previous session?

Comment: Mine retains the session.  Do you have some odd extensions?  Did you upgrade to 1.0?

Comment: I would actually like the opposite - I want a clean session every time I open it

Answer (score 0):

It **should** remember what folder you had open, so it's hard to know exactly why not. Here are some things to try though:

1. If you have any extensions installed, try uninstalling them. (If that fixes it, you can reinstall them one by one to see which one was the problem).
2. If you select *Debug > Show Developer Tools* in the menu, are there any errors listed in the Console tab?
3. If you select *Help > Show Extensions Folder* and then go up one level, is there a `state.json` file there? If so, try deleting/renaming it to see if that fixes things. If not, make sure the permissions on that folder are ok.